# Use of "the" after "each of"

Tags: definite-articles

Hi I'd like to ask if this text is correct. I believe that "the" is missing from the sentence and it shoul be: "...each of the five level categories:". Am I correct? If it is correct as it is, why?

"Ten winners will be announced in each of five level categories: 450-499, 500-599, 600-799, 800-999, 1000+.

Comment: Link has been fixed.

Comment: Links aren't reliable in the long run. It would be better to include the quote textually in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definite article would only be possible in your advertisement if the five categories had been [previously mentioned or defined.](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/definite-and-indefinite-articles.html)

> Once upon a time there was ***a*** princess who lived in a high tower. ***The*** princess had long golden hair.

Which princess? The one in the high tower. Now that we know which princess, we can use the definite article.

Since there is no plural indefinite article in English, we just use the bare word.

> A team of researchers measured [each of ten subjects'](https://gmatclub.com/forum/a-team-of-researchers-measured-each-of-ten-subjects-reactio-123873.html) reaction time to a certain stimulus and calculated the mean, median, and standard deviation of the measurements.

This is the beginning of a description of a research project and the first time any subjects are mention. Thus they are indefinite until defined by this sentence. Which subjects? The ones whose reaction time was measured. I can now refer to them as *the* ten subjects.